# Python Tkinter Root Title doesn't work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't seem to title my windows. They all have the title "Tk".I believe my code is correct, so correct me if this is wrong...

```
from Tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
root.title="Title"
root.mainloop()
```

The title is still Tk(). Could I maybe `from Tkinter import Tk as MyTitle`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
root.title("Title")
```

Try that, its a method you invoke and pass in the parameter.