# Python Tkinter window title will not display any text other than the word Title

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, pycharm

I am attempting to learn Python. The IDE being used is PyCharm in Ubuntu 16.10. The project interpreter has the following modules loaded: PyOpenFDM, cycler, glob2, matplotlib, numpy, pandas, pip, pyparsing, python-dateutil, pytz, scipy, setuptools, simplekml, six and wheel.

I am using the free tutorials on UDemy.com. The tutorial I am currently on has this example:

```
import simplekml
import pandas
import tkinter

df = pandas.read_csv("Coordinates.csv")
kml = simplekml.Kml()
for lon, lat in zip(df["Longitude"], df["Latitude"]):
    kml.newpoint(name="SomePlace", coords=[(lon, lat)])
kml.save("C:\\out\\Points.kml")

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("KML Generator")
root.geometry("500x300")
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="This window generates a KML file.")
label.pack()
browseButton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Browse")
browseButton.pack
root.mainloop()
```

On the instructor's system the above script works as expected without error.

While Googling I found very few other issues where there was nothing displayed in the title bar. The few the I did find where either solved by correcting a typo (I have checked my code against the instructor's 4 times) or by adding *.title("Some Title"). Searching StackOverflow lead me to the post [Python Tkinter Root Title doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949265/python-tkinter-root-title-doesnt-work) which prompted me to change 'root.title("KML Generator")' to 'root.title("Title")'. Then the title 'Title' displayed in the window. But when I change the title anything else the title is not displayed. I have not yet found any combinations of letters, other than 'Title', that will display in the title bar of a window.

Another problem is that browseButton is not displayed.

Right-clicking on root.title brings up a context menu where I can click Go to --> Declaration and PyCharm opens a file editing window and moves the focus to:

```
def wm_title(self, string=None):
    """Set the title of this widget."""
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'title', self._w, string)
title = wm_title
```

But I don't know enough for this to do me any good in solving the problems mentioned above.

Anyone have any idea on what the problem is?

Comment: The browse button is not showing because you failed to call the `pack()` method. Use `browseButton.pack()`. As for the title, works for me. My dialog has "KML Generator" as the title.

Comment: The command for setting the title is really `wm_title` so use `root.title('any old text')` but the `title` method is an alias for `wm_title` so should be fine as used (and is for me). The text should not matter - any unicode string should be fine. eg: `root.title('мир')`

Comment: create minimal version - only `Tk()`, `title()` and `mainloop()` - and test it in PyCharm and without PyCharm.

Comment: Feel a bit silly for not seeing I was missing the parens for the browseButton pack, guess that will happen when not at all familiar with the syntax. I believe the title should work as is but still have no idea why it doesn't.  Thanks patthoyts. Created a minimal version as furas suggested, only four lines of code and still title only shows I mentioned above. Going to try to get minimalist script to work later.

Comment: PyCharm is using Python 3.5.1 but in a terminal python --version shows version 2.7.12 in use. When attempting to reinstall both python and python-tk for both versions 2 and 3 the apt-get response indicates that both python and python-tk are installed fro both versions. But, at a terminal I run python in interactive mode, the command 'import tkinter' i receive the error message "ImportError: No module named tkinter"

Comment: Turns out when importing tkinter with python version 2.7 the statement is "import Tkinter" and in python version 3.5 the correct statement is "import tkinter". One uses capital T and the other lowercase t. Which means I will have problems writing scripts in version 3.5, which is what installed with PyCharm and version 2.7 which is loaded with Ubuntu 16.04. More research revealed that Ubuntu 16.04 strongly relies on Python 2.7.

Comment: Tried running a minimalist version, furas suggestion, and had the same results. The Tk window is displayed, but there is no title. Unless, the statement used is 'root.title("Title")', any other text than Title spelled with a capital T results in no title being displayed in the title bar.

Comment: The problem of setting a value for the window title is still present after using a minimal of 4 lines of code. But, since the actual problem is following along the free Python tutorial on UDemy.com and since it was the lack of a pair of braces, pointed out by patthoyts, that was causing this problem. I can now resume following the tutorial. Thank You patthoyts.